# Need Help related to ADODB VBA Macro SQL SERVER

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2008, adodb

I am trying to load data to my SQL server 2008 R2 Database using VB macro from an excel sheet.
I have already written a macro that was working fine for one table ,but when i modify it to insert data into another table i am getting the error

`Runtime Error'2147217900(80040e14)'
[microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL SERVER]Incorrect syntax near '9'`

and when i press debug this line is getting highlighted

`oCm.Execute iRecAffected`

The table that i am trying to update has 6 fields  a,b,c,d,e,f of type int,int,int,datetime,datetime and int

I believe the error is because there is something i am not doing for datetime fields in this line

`oCm.CommandText = "Insert Into Table (a, b, c, d, e, f) Values (" & a & " ," & b & " ," & c & "," & d & "," & e & "," & f & ")"`

can some one please tell me what could be the issue.

`

```
Dim DestinationWorkBook       As Workbook
Dim SourceWorkBook    As Workbook
Dim DestinationWorkBook1       As Workbook
Dim SourceWorkBook1    As Workbook
Dim oCm As ADODB.Command
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Date
Dim e As Date
Dim f As Integer
Dim iRecAffected As Integer
Dim CurrentRow           As Integer
Set DestinationWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
Set SourceWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
Set DestinationWorkBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Set SourceWorkBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim b                    As String
Dim rngRange             As Range
Dim a                    As String

     LoopContinue = True


     CurrentRow3 = 2
    loop1 = True

     CurrentRow = 2
     DestinationWorkBook.Activate
     Worksheets("errors").Select
     Rows("1:1500").Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
     SourceWorkBook.Activate
     Worksheets("Final_output").Select
Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
 Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
 Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
 oCon.ConnectionString = "deleted"
 oCon.Open
 Set oCm = New ADODB.Command
 oCm.ActiveConnection = oCon
 While loop1 = True
 a = (Range("A" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 b = (Range("B" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 c = (Range("C" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 d = (Range("D" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 e = (Range("E" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 f = (Range("F" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value)
 If Len(Range("A" & CStr(CurrentRow)).Value) = 0 Then
 loop1 = False
 End If
  If (loop1 <> False) Then

 oCm.CommandText = "Insert Into Table (a, b, c, d, e, f) Values (" & a & " ," & b & " ," & c & "," & d & "," & e & "," & f & ")"
oCm.Execute iRecAffected
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
End If
Wend
oCon.Close
End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that Table is a reserved word in ADO.

Comment: no i have renamed table name before posting its student,actually i have renamed data fields plus removed the connection string on purpose

Comment: You also initialise the variable loop1 to true, and then use it to confirm that the loop has been executed at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around the datetime values in the CommandText - e.g. `",'" & d & "','" & e & "',"`

The date literal format with ADO is usually `#mm/dd/yy#` and I think that you could only use any other literal format if it was supported by the particular driver you are using. Enclosing the value in quotes should get around this.